# Is it possible to change the Firefox browser settings via Vue.js application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kerberos, devops

In my project I made `SSO` (single sign-on) by `Kerberos`. When I make request from client application (`Vue.js`) to Kerberos server it don't work in Firefox browser. By default, Kerberos support in Firefox is disabled. To enable it, user need to open the browser configuration window (go to `about:config` in the address bar). Then in the parameter (`network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`) specify the addresses of the web servers, for which client are going to use Kerberos authentication. How can you understand this is inconvenient for the user.

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to somehow change the Firefox browser settings via Vue.js application when accessing the page?

**Vue.JS**:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const APIAuth = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'kerberos_server_url',
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Imagine a web where any site could change your browser parameters, it would be a big mess .. The only thing you can do is make a little popup or something like that to inform your user that they have to enable this parameter.

Comment: You are absolutely right, you have dispelled my doubts.